# Understanding the use of the phrase "as best she might"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Reading *The Small House at Allington* by Anthony Trollope I came across the expression **as best she might** in the following quote:

> But she had been a good daughter, assisting her mother, **as best she might**, in all family troubles, and never repining at the cold, colourless, unlovely life which had been vouchsafed to her.

I think I understand its meaning from [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44194/what-is-the-structure-in-as-best-you-can) and from some of the adequate answers.

I'm aware that the author wrote the book almost two centuries ago and as such the expression might be archaic but I don't think it would be appropriate to say it is a sloppy language use.

However, I wonder what would it sound like if used in today's English? Would it sound fine or weird?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(as+best+she+might)%2C(as+well+as+she+could)%2C(the+best+she+could)%2C(the+best+she+might)&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28as%20best%20she%20might%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28as%20well%20as%20she%20could%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28the%20best%20she%20could%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28the%20best%20she%20might%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: As an aside, I made a quick search (electronically) through the all 34 books that I posses of the author in question and found out that this construct appears 115 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be weird to hear it in modern day English, and it was never a popular phrase, as you can tell by [this graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20best%20as%20he%20might%2Cas%20best%20as%20he%20could%2C%20as%20best%20as%20she%20might%2Cas%20best%20as%20she%20could%2C%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20best%20as%20he%20might%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20best%20as%20he%20could%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20best%20as%20she%20could%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: That's not a useful graph for this discussion, as it does not include the actual phrase in question. Here is a more comprehensive graph, modified from TRomano's comment to the original question: [goo.gl/4LIf0n]